# LazyColum Headers and Sub-headers

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, lazycolumn

I am trying to create a `LazyColumn` with a sticky header and a sticky sub-header.
The functionality I would like to achieve what is demonstrated in [this GIF](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kenber/DoubleStickyHeadersList/master/samplePicture/sample.gif).

My source code is as follows:

**The data item which will be used**

```
class Item(
val type: String, // Will be used as header
val subType: String, // Will be used as sub-header
val title: String,
val description: String,
val imageUrl: String)
```

**An example of the item usage**

```
Item("Movie", "Action",
        "Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings",
        "Shang-Chi, the master of unarmed weaponry-based Kung Fu, is forced to " +
                "confront his past after being drawn into the Ten Rings organization.",
    "https://threepixelslab.gr/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Shang-Chi-and-the-Legend-of-the-Ten-Rings.jpg")
```

**The list composing**

```
@Composable
fun MainList(data: List<Item>) {
    val mainGroup = data.groupBy { it.type }
    LazyColumn {
        mainGroup.forEach { (type, groupedData) ->
            val subGroup = groupedData.groupBy { it.subType }
            stickyHeader {
                Header(text = type)
            }
            item {
                LazyColumn {
                    subGroup.forEach { (subType, subGroupedData) ->
                        stickyHeader { Header(text = subType) }
                        items(subGroupedData) {
                            SimpleItem(item = it)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The error**

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nesting scrollable in the same
> direction layouts like LazyColumn and
> Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()) is not allowed. If you want to add a
> header before the list of items please take a look on LazyColumn
> component which has a DSL api which allows to first add a header via
> item() function and then the list of items via items().
>
> at androidx.compose.foundation.ScrollKt.assertNotNestingScrollableContainers-K40F9xA(Scroll.kt:370)
> at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListKt$LazyList$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyList.kt:96)
> at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListKt$LazyList$1.invoke(LazyList.kt:95)
> at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:345)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:43)
> at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValuesModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Padding.kt:417)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
> at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:219)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:116)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:116)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:116)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$3.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:100)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$3.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:128)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:63)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:71)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNode.kt:1227)
> at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnImplKt$rowColumnMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(RowColumnImpl.kt:89)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:43)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$3.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:100)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$3.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:128)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:63)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:71)
> at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNode.kt:1227)
> at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyMeasuredItemProvider.getAndMeasure-ZjPyQlc(LazyMeasuredItemProvider.kt:50)
> at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListMeasureKt.measureLazyList-9CW8viI(LazyListMeasure.kt:145)
> at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListKt$LazyList$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyList.kt:152)
> at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListKt$LazyList$1.invoke(LazyList.kt:95)
> at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:345)

Is it possible to implement this kind of list in Compose?

Comment: You can't do this with out of the box LazyColumn as you are trying to use 2 different kind of sticky headers at the same time. Your exception comes from having a vertically scrolling composable (LazyList) within another vertically scrolling composable (LazyList). You'll need to write a custom solution.

Comment: @Francesc Do you have any example of something custom made for Compose? Just to take an idea at first.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have any examples of this nature, you may need to look into the LazyList sticky headers implementation from the Compose libraries and expand on that.